# Appending form variables on parent from modal popup not working

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a modal popup with a form, and I am trying to get the values, on submit, to append a ul list on the page.

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="breakfast">
<p>BREAKFAST</p>
<p>
<ul class="breakfastlist">
</ul></p>
<p align="center"><a href="#breakfastPop" rel="modal:open">ADD FOOD</a></p>
  </div>

<div id="breakfastPop" class="modal" style="max-width: 680px;">
<div id="custom" style="background-color: fff; border: 0;">
<p>Select your food for BREAKFAST</p><br>
<div>FOOD / PREPARATION / PORTION<br>
<form class="breakfastform">
<?php
include('includes/mealpicker.php');
?></div>
<div style="text-align: center;"># PROTEINS<br>
<input type="text" name="num_protein" style="width: 45px;"></div>
<div style="text-align: center;"># CARBS<br>
<input type="text" name="num_carbs" style="width: 45px;"></div>
</div>
    <p align="center"><input type='submit' value="ADD FOOD" /></p>
</form>
</div>
```

This is the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#breakfastPop form').on('submit', function(){
var to_append = $('select') +' - '+ $('input[name=num_protein]') +' - '+     $('input[name=num_carbs]');
$('.breakfastlist').append('<li>'+ to_append + '</li>');

$(this).parent().hide();
return false;
});
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: So right now, you're actually appending the entire selected elements themselves, rather than any textual value. use, for example, `$('input[name=num_protein]').val()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I say in my comment, you're inserting the object wrapper around each input, rather than the value of the input itself. Try this for a start:

```js
$('#breakfastPop form').on('submit', function(evt){

var to_append = $('select option:selected').val() 
      +' - '+ $('input[name=num_protein]').val()
      +' - '+     $('input[name=num_carbs]').val();
$('.breakfastlist').append('<li>'+ to_append + '</li>');


$.modal.close();
return false;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>

<div id="breakfast">
  <p>BREAKFAST</p>
  <p>
    <ul class="breakfastlist">
    </ul>
  </p>
  <p align="center"><a href="#breakfastPop" rel="modal:open">ADD FOOD</a></p>
</div>

<div id="breakfastPop" class="modal" style="max-width: 680px;">
  <div id="custom" style="background-color: fff; border: 0;">
    <p>Select your food for BREAKFAST</p>
    <br>
    <div>FOOD / PREPARATION / PORTION
      <br>
    </div>
      <form class="breakfastform">
      <select name="food_name">
        <option value="">-- Select --</option>
        <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
        <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
        <option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
        <option value="Date">Date</option>
      </select>
    <div style="text-align: center;"># PROTEINS
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="num_protein" style="width: 45px;">
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center;"># CARBS
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="num_carbs" style="width: 45px;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <p align="center">
    <input class="close-modal" type='submit' value="ADD FOOD" />
  </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you - I ended up figuring it out a little bit ago - but what you pasted here was darn close to what I came up with and I appreciate the help :)